# How to change timeout in machine config in azure platform and/or emulator?

Tags: wcf, azure, config

We are hosting a WCF service in a azure webrole. We get a timeoutException if we want to send large files. We've adjusted the send and receive timeout in the config files on the client as well as on the serverside.

Even after these adjustments this exception is still occuring after +- 10 minutes.

We think we have to adjust the machine config in azure, but we don't know how to do this.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably working with blobs.

With blobs you can specify a BlobRequestOptions with in it a timeout value.

Try to change it like this:

```
BlobRequestOptions largeBlobDownloadOptions = new BlobRequestOptions()
{
  Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60) // Larger timeout for larger file
};

blob.DownloadToFile(largeBlobDownloadOptions);
```